# Dubbi sul tempo verbale corretto

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

La situazione è questa: chiedo ad un mio amico di contattarmi dopo il suo esame per dirmi com'è andato e lui si scorda.

"Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato" 
o 
"Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @user1762!

Comment: Al presente: "Gli ho chiesto di dirmi come è andata", al passato "Gli avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andata". Non userei il condizionale, anche se parlando si usi molto.

Comment: @Josh61:  Ma perché l'indicativo al presente e il congiuntivo al passato?

Comment: “Ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato” sarebbe impeccabile se la richiesta originale fosse stata di una previsione (“ti chiedo di dirmi come andrà”), visto che il condizionale si usa anche per il “futuro nel passato”. Qui la situazione è complicata dal fatto che vorremmo un “futuro anteriore nel passato”, cioè la versione passata di “ti chiedo di dirmi come sarà andato”. Tutto sommato, mi suona meglio quindi “...come fosse andato”, ma non la metto come risposta perché è un'opinione un po' a orecchio.

Comment: "MENO MALE CHE TI AVEVO CHIESTO DI DIRMI COME ANDAVA" è la versione corretta nel contesto amichevole descritto in premessa e riconoscibile dall'esordio con "MENO MALE" nonché dal 'tono' generalmente confidenziale dell'appunto. Comunque benvenuto/a e buona permanenza fra noi.

Comment: Questioni di sfumature, e al di là della correttezza formale, *credo* (!) che l'opzione "sarebbe andato" sia l'unica in grado di non lasciare ambiguità. Non sono d'accordo con @ElberichSchneider nella misura in cui anche nel contesto colloquiale e nonostante la presenza del "meno male", "ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come *andava*" è 1) ambiguo e 2) molto brutto. E lo dico da sostenitore dell'indicativo molto libero e disinvolto nel linguaggio parlato.

Comment: A me "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato" suona proprio sbagliato, sembra che implichi una condizione a seguire, tipo: "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato nel caso tu l'avessi sostenuto" (dove peraltro andrebbe bene anche "sarebbe" al posto di "fosse"). A me sembra meglio la seconda, anche se come già detto da altri fa *leggermente* storcere il naso anche quella.

Comment: Secondo questo [sito web](http://www.adgblog.it/2012/01/13/discorso-diretto-%E2%80%93-discorso-indiretto/), nel passaggio da discorso diretto a discorso indiretto, se il verbo principale è al passato, il futuro anteriore (in rapporto con un altro futuro) diventa trapassato congiuntivo. Esempio: Disse: “Ti scriverò dopo che sarò ritornato a casa” --> "Disse che le avrebbe scritto dopo che fosse ritornato a casa".

Comment: Comunque, [questo sito](http://italiano.org.gt/documentazioni/DISCORSO%20DIRETTO%20E%20DISCORSO%20INDIRETTO%20CORSO%2011%20CALUSAC.pdf) e anche [quest'altro](http://musicaitaliana.wikispaces.com/file/view/Discorso+indiretto+seconda+parte.pdf) affermano che il futuro anteriore diventa condizionale composto o congiuntivo trapassato. Esempio: Pietro ha detto: “Quando avrò finito questo lavoro andrò in ferie.” --> Pietro ha detto che quando avrebbe finito / avesse finito quel lavoro sarebbe andato in ferie.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ritengo che la forma in "fosse" sia quella corretta. Prova ad aggiungere un contesto temporale: "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato, una volta finito", VS. "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato, una volta finito". Come sottolinea DaG nei commenti, il "sarebbe" sarebbe appropriato in caso di previsione, ma siccome l'azione è richiesta una volta terminato l'esame, e cioè quando ormai è un fatto al passato, la forma in "fosse"  è, a mio parere, quella corretta.

Comunque, in contesto colloquiale, anche dire "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di farmi sapere come andava" è del tutto accettabile.

Comment: A giudicar da quello che ho trovato su Internet, sembra che entrambe le forme siano corrette. Disconosco se in questo caso esista qualche motivo per preferire una sull'altra. Non credo però che la ragione possa essere il fatto di chiedere su un fatto (l'esame) ormai passato perché questo è piuttosto proprio del discorso indiretto quando il tempo della proposizione reggente è al passato. Il problema è come passare dal discorso diretto al discorso indiretto.

Comment: Discorso diretto: Ti avevo chiesto: "Dimmi come sarà andato (quando lo saprai)" --> Discorso indiretto: Ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come ???

Comment: A me "meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato" suona come se l'esame fosse già stato fatto al momento della domanda, mentre "meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato" suona come se al momento della domanda l'esame fosse stato nel futuro.

Comment: Cioè "Dimmi come andrà" -> "Ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato"; "Dimmi com'è andato" -> "Ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato"

Comment: @DenisNardin: Il problema è che, nel discorso diretto, la frase è: "Dimmi come sarà andato".

Comment: @Charo A me suona estremamente sgrammaticata. Perchè l'uso del futuro anteriore? Non credo di aver mai sentito niente del genere

Comment: @DenisNardin: Perché indica un'azione futura (come andrà l'esame) che accadrà prima di un'altra azione futura (il fatto di informare l'amico).

Comment: @Charo Boh a me suona comunque molto strana, sia in un contesto formale che in un contesto informale. Non riesco a capire come funziona ngram se no cercherei dei dati più precisi ma per quel che conta io non credo di averla mai sentita usare

Answer (score 2):

L'esame di Biagio si è tenuto lunedì 2 novembre.

1. Domenica 1° novembre Alice ha detto a Biagio: *«Appena saprai come sarà andato l'esame, dimmelo, per favore»*. Avrebbe anche potuto dirgli così, in modo più colloquiale: *«Appena sai come è andato l'esame, dimmelo, per favore»*. Mercoledì 3 novembre Biagio ha saputo che l'esame è andato bene ma non ha detto niente ad Alice. Oggi Alice ha incontrato Biagio e, offesa, gli ha detto: *«Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come **sarebbe** andato»*.
2. Domenica 1° novembre Alice ha detto a Biagio: *«In bocca al lupo»*. Avrebbe anche potuto dirgli un'altra frase meno educata che coinvolge una balena. La mattina di mercoledì 3 novembre Biagio ha saputo che l'esame è andato bene. Nel pomeriggio di mercoledì 3 novembre Alice ha scritto un SMS a Biagio: *«Come è andato l'esame?»*; Biagio non le ha risposto. Oggi Alice ha incontrato Biagio e, offesa, gli ha detto: *«Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come **fosse** andato»*.

Spero si capisca la differenza tra i due casi.

Per un motivo piuttosto sottile, ad ogni modo, usare la frase 2 nel contesto 1 è meno sbagliato che usare la frase 1 nel contesto 2. Ecco perché:

- *Ti avevo chiesto* = 1° novembre (nel contesto 1)
- *di dirmi* = 3 novembre
- *come **fosse/sarebbe** andato* = 2 novembre

Il 2 novembre è il futuro del 1° novembre ma è anche il passato del 3 novembre. Se lo pensi come passato del 2 novembre, va bene anche usare *fosse*, ma la cosa più logica è pensarlo come futuro del 1° novembre, quindi usare *sarebbe*.

Vediamo invece perché nel contesto 2 è giusto solo *sarebbe*:

- *Ti avevo chiesto* = 3 novembre
- *di dirmi* = 3 novembre
- *come **fosse** andato* = 2 novembre

Il 2 novembre è il passato di entrambi gli altri verbi: sia del *chiedere* di Alice sia del *dire* di Biagio, che succedono entrambi il 3 novembre. Si può quindi usare solo *sarebbe*.

Comment: Concordo in pieno. Ottima risposta!

Answer (score 0):

Suggerisco: "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come era andata" (la cosa, la faccenda, l'avventura) o "come era andato" (l'esame). Mi sembra più semplice e chiarissimo.

Answer (score 0):

La forma corretta e'

> **meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come fosse andato**

Questa forma, che usa il modo Congiuntivo (*fosse andato*), e' la forma corretta da usare nel caso in cui l'esito descritto dalla frase subordinata sia ormai noto.

La forma 'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato', che usa il modo Condizionale (*sarebbe andato*), deve invece essere usata nel caso in cui la comunicazione  avvenga prima dello svolgimento dell'esame, situazione nella quale sussite un dubbio 
sull'esito dell'esame.

Si veda [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-nel-passato_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) su l'uso del Condizionale Passato per esprimere il concetto di futuro nel passato.

Introducendo un dato temporale nelle frasi, senza modificarne la sostanza del significato, si possono mettere in evidenza queste differenze nella struttura temporale. Si confronti infatti:

'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi **dopo** come fosse andato'

con

'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi **dopo** come *sarebbe andato'

che suona evidentemente stonata appunto per l'uso del Condizionale (una forma dubitativa) in riferimento ad un fatto ormai avvenuto. Similmente, la frase

'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come **speravi che** sarebbe andato'

suona corretta dal punto di vista dei tempi, mentre la frase

'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come **speravi che** fosse andato'

ci rende l'immagine mentale che l'esame sia stato sostenuto, ma gli esaminatori si siano riservati di esprimersi sull'esito, che quindi non e' ancora noto all'esaminando. Questa seconda frase di per se' e' corretta, ma ha un significato diverso da quello che si voleva dare.

La differenza tra le due frasi potrebbe forse essere colta piu' facilmente riconducendo i modi verbali all'Indicativo, pratica comune nel linguaggio parlato ma grammaticalmente scorretta. Le formulazioni che dal punto di vista della sequenza temporale degli eventi sono corrette, sono: 
'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi (dopo l'esame) come *era andato'
e
'meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi (prima dell'esame) come *andra''

Answer (score -1):

A me suona meglio "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sia andata", ma non saprei spiegarmi perchè.

Peggio mi suona "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come sarebbe andato", che mi suona rinviare comunque a un qualche condizionale: "Meno male che ti avevo chiesto di dirmi come l'esame sarebbe andato [secondo te]  se la commissione fosse stata al completo"

EDIT

```
1  - Io chiedo [oggi] di dirmi [oggi] come l'esame [domani] andrà.  
[chiedo oggi una previsione su quello che domani succederà]
```

Quale delle due seguenti suona corretta? Se 2a), come distinguere il significato tra 2a) e 1)? E, 2b) è  grammaticalmente corretta?

```
2a - Io chiedo [oggi] di dirmi [domani] come l'esame [domani] andrà. 
[chiedo che domani mi sia detto il risultato]

2b - Io chiedo [oggi] di dirmi [domani] come l'esame [domani] sarà andato    
[chiedo che domani mi sia detto il risultato]
```

Versioni con tempo passato:

```
1*/2a* - Io chiesi [ieri] di dirmi [ieri] come l'esame  [oggi] sarebbe andato       
[ricordo di aver chiesto una previsione]
```

La seguente potrebbe essere la versione  di 2b)?

```
2b* - Io chiesi [ieri] di dirmi [oggi] come l'esame [oggi] sia andato            
[avevo chiesto che oggi il risultato mi sia detto]
```

Comment: «Nelle subordinate rette da frasi principali con tempi narrativi indica invece il cosiddetto futuro nel passato:
(1) disse che sarebbe arrivato oggi.» (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/condizionale_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)